# How to pass value of javascript variable to java variable

Tags: javascript, java

```js
  function popolaSelect() {
          var arrayusers = ['lucapelle', 'alessiourb'],
            users = document.getElementById('users');
          for (nomi in arrayusers) {
            users.add(new Option(arrayusers[nomi]));
          };
        }

        function submitForm() {
          var objCombo = document.getElementById("users");
          var quser = objCombo.options[objCombo.selectedIndex].value;
        }
```

```html
<html>

  <body class="text-center" onload="popolaSelect();">
    <form class="form-signin"><select class="form-signin" id="users"></select><br><br><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Autorizza</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2018-2019</p>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

```
html+="function submitForm() {";
            html+="var objCombo = document.getElementById(\"users\");";
            html+="var quser = objCombo.options[objCombo.selectedIndex].value;";
            html+="}";
            html+="</script>";
```

I'm writing an html page in Java, I want to get the value of var quser and store it in a variable in Java.. is that possible?

The code rappresent the script with which i get the value of the selected users but i don't know how to pass `var quser` value in a local variabile in my java program

I'm new on java programming

Comment: javascript to java ,cross a bridge called ajax :)

Comment: @ShubhDixit can you make me an example please?

Comment: @ShubhDixit Spring should also work here

Comment: @HarryStylesheet well spring is also a java side ,and moreover he has'nt emphasized on any framework yhe is using

Answer (score 0):

Since JS code runs on the user's browser and Java runs on your server, the only way to pass data from Javascript to Java is by doing an Ajax call. On your server, you need a API endpoint which accepts requests, then after receiving the desired data, you can handle it on your Java program.

Check:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks but I'm inexperienced, can you poste me a simple example?